# Referanceing venet0:0 and venet0:1 in iptables on OpenVZ

Tags: networking, iptables, vps, openvz

I have an Ubuntu vps that is hosted with openvz. For a while now I have had trouble using the interface names in iptables, such as: (edited)

```
 -A INPUT -i venet0:0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

The problem is iptables does not seem to understand what venet0:0 is. I also have a rather odd network configuration. Output of `ifconfig -a`

```
 gre0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-20-4A-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
     NOARP  MTU:1476  Metric:1
     RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
     TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
     collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
     RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

 gretap0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
     BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1476  Metric:1
     RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
     TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
     collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
     RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
    inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
    inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
    UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
    RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
    RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

 venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
    inet addr:127.0.0.2  P-t-P:127.0.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
    UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:44859 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:37950 errors:0 dropped:103 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
    RX bytes:9472928 (9.0 MiB)  TX bytes:8953521 (8.5 MiB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
    inet addr:xx.xx.xx.xx  P-t-P:xx.xx.xx.xx  Bcast:xx.xx.xx.xx  Mask:255.255.255.255
    UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1

venet0:1  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
     inet addr:xy.xy.xy.xy  P-t-P:xy.xy.xy.xy  Bcast:xy.xy.xy.xy  Mask:255.255.255.255
     UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

I emailed my vps provider and asked how to assign interfaces such as `eth0` and `eth1` for iptables interface referencing, and they replied that it was not possible, but that the `venet` interfaces could be used as such. However, when I try to use them, nothing happens.

I know there must be something I am doing wrong or don't understand. I also don't understand what the `gre0` and `gretap0` interfaces are, or what they are for. Any ideas?

Comment: Your syntax is asking for an IP address whereas you are giving an interface name. Instead try this `-A INPUT -i venet0:0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`. If that still doesn't work (unsure about :0 type interfaces), then try this `-A INPUT -i venet0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT'

Comment: Actually I made a mistake when I wrote the post, I just corrected it, thank you. I have tried doing what you suggest. I can use venet0 for openvpn routing for some reason, like: `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o venet0 -j SNAT --to-source x.x.x.x` , but otherwise it seems to fail. Also venet0 is the second local host interface.

Comment: I have never used interface aliasing before, but I do not think (and I did some reading) you can specify them in iptables. I don't think you need the `-m tcp` part. So the suggestion is to add the destination address as an additional condition: `-A INPUT -i venet0 -d  xx.xx.xx.xx -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: You're right, I don't think that can be done, but this is a perfect workaround.  Would i use `-i lo` for the other IP address than?

Comment: Based on my current understanding, which might be wrong, no. For the other ip address, the one that is related to `venet0:1`, the line, for the same port, and for example, would be `-A INPUT -i venet0 -d xy.xy.xy.xy -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`. I'll convert all this to an answer if you confirm we are on the right track here.

Comment: Yes, do that and I will accept it.  You are correct, that works for both IP's and does the same thing. Thank you, this has drive me mad for some time now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot specify an aliased interface name with iptables, only an actual interface name. The trick is to add the destination IP address as an additional condition. Also you do not need the `-m tcp` part. So if you wanted to accept traffic to port 80 on both aliased interfaces, the rules would be:

```
-A INPUT -i venet0 -d xx.xx.xx.xx -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i venet0 -d xy.xy.xy.xy -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```